# how am I gonna call a sub class with "ByVal control as IRibbonControl" from Button1_Click?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office365

Do you have any idea to call "reportPhishing" sub class from "button1_click"?

[image]

well I tried different ways like:

- adding `ByVal control as IRibbonControl` in Button1_Click but it seems to give me this:
  `Method 'Button1_Click' cannot handle Event 'Click' because they do not have the same signature`
- changing `e As RibbonControlEventArgs` to `control As RibbonControlEventArgs` seems to give me this: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`

How am I able to do it?

Comment: Most likely, you will want to cast `sender` to `IRibbonControl`.  You can use `TryCast` if there's any question about whether the cast will succeed, otherwise `DirectCast` or `CType` will do it (and throw an exception if the cast fails).

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong(still a beginner tho-) but is this it: ```TryCast(sender, IRibbonControl)```

Comment: That's right, the result will be either the original object now in the form of an `IRibbonControl` or else it will be `Nothing`.

Comment: omgomgomg thx so much!! It worked :,D